# Prove $\sum {b_n}^{1\over2}\dot\,{1\over{n^{\alpha}}}\,$ converges given $\sum b_n\,$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $b_n>0$ and $\sum b_n\,$ converges, prove $\sum {b_n}^{1\over2}\dot\,{1\over{n^{\alpha}}}\,$ converges for all $\alpha>{1\over2}$.

I know 
${b_n}^{1\over2}\dot\,{1\over{n^{\alpha}}}\leq{b_n}^{1\over2}\dot\,{1\over{n^{1\over2}}}$

Since $b_n$ converges to $0$, I cannot say ${b_n}^{1\over2}\leq b_n$. This seemingly eliminates my hopes of using the direct comparison test. My next guess would be to use Abel's test, but I am having difficulty showing the partial sum sequence of ${b_n}^{1\over2}$ is bounded. What would be a good next step? I am trying to avoid using the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, as it was not covered in class. But if that is the "common tool" used here, please let me know, and I will pursue it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $n^\alpha$ instead of $j^\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowledge of Cauchy-Schwarz, we can use that
$$
0\le\left(b_n^{1/2}-\frac1{n^\alpha}\right)^2=b_n-2b_n^{1/2}\frac1{n^\alpha}+\frac1{n^{2\alpha}}
$$
implies
$$
b_n^{1/2}\frac1{n^\alpha}\le\frac12\left(b_n+\frac1{n^{2\alpha}}\right)
$$
Sum both sides to get that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n^{1/2}\frac1{n^\alpha}\le\frac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{2\alpha}}\right)
$$
Now use the fact that $\alpha\gt\frac12$.

Comment: I essentially reproved Cauchy-Schwarz above.

Answer (score 1):

It is a straight forward application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thanks, I will pursue this further. Just curious, assuming no knowledge of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, is there a solution to this accessible (in terms of difficulty) to an undergraduate student?

Comment: You can use the inequality $2ab\le a^2+b^2$ as in robjohn's answer. But any student knowing Abel's test probably knows the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.